# Validating IOS Application Archive

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

I have created an archive for a new version of a product already on the app store. I have incremented the version number to 2. I have created version 2 in tuned.

When I go to Organizer>Archives, I see my correct app name,  icon,  Version 2, and correct bundle identifier.

When I click VALIDATE then NEXT to log on to iTune connect,I get a dialog saying:

```
 Choose a profile to sign with.
```

At that point, the application name is wrong (being the name of a test application I created a while ago). This is displayed in a non-changeable label. The provisioning profile looks correct, being the only value in the drop down list.

The validation then fails with three messages:

```
The bundle is invalid. The bundle identifier is already in use by a different  software package.
```

The bundle identifier cannot be changed from its current value 'Test Bundle'. If you want to change your bundle identifier, you will need to create a new application in iTunes Connect.

The bundle identifier matches the name of the one I create for the test application. However, if I got to General>identity the project has a the correct bundle id (Not 'test Bundle').

In other words, the General>Identify>Bundle Identifier matches the bundle when I am asked to select the bundle identifier. However, the application name does not match the application name of the project and the bundle ID reported in validation errors does not match the bundle ID from General>Identify>Bundle Identifier.

Where is the wrong application name and bundle ID being picked up?

Comment: when you create a new app entry in your iTunesConnect.apple.com account, and turned it to "ready to upload binary", what's the bundle id you have used there? does it match the one in your provisioning profile? Application Name, version numbers and bundle identifiers should match between iTunesConnect and your binary.(its possible that when you created the app on iTC some other bundle id was selected)

Comment: You have the correct answer. Have to change it to "ready to upload binary". I would never have figured that out from the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

posting from my comment for further reference:

when you create a new app entry in your iTunesConnect.apple.com account, and turned it to "ready to upload binary", what's the bundle id you have used there?

does it match the one in your provisioning profile?

Application Name, version numbers and bundle identifiers should match between iTunesConnect and your binary.(its possible that when you created the app on iTC some other bundle id was selected)